# Get single row when 2 column values are repeated

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Thanks in advance.

My customer gets a shippment of this particular item which has an ID based on their requirment. On this perticular requested item the ID is definied as follows.

1. Barcode # - Machine generated
2. Visible # - Manual serial number

On the item itself the barcode's actual value is not show instead they should the equivalent visibleid.

```
        Example
        -------

||||||||| <Barcode # - C007587>
 C000001  <Visible # - C000001>
```

The manufacturer of this item though generate and print the Barcode # and Visible # on, the number do get repeated. They provide my client with the final excel sheet and the excel data has to be imported to the DB which is done. But upon checking we found the data has duplicate id.

```
DB Schema with row sample

SRNO    BarcodeID    VisibleID
----    ---------    ---------
1       C007587      C000001
2       C000001      C011704
```

The operators use a barcode scanner to scan the ID present on the item most of the time but sometimes they also manually keyin the value.

```
SQL Query I am using is as follows
----------------------------------

select * from <table> where barcodeid='C000001' or VisibleID='C000001'
```

When execute the above SQL code we get 2 rows for obvious reason, where I need to get only 1 row. (As long there is no repeated values in either one of the columns we get single row result which works for us).

#### NOTE: I would not able able to differentiate if the operator key-in or scan the ID code NOR I would be able to modify the excel file we receive.

Hence request any suggestion on how to tackle this issue and get the actual result.

Comment: +1 Horrible design IMHO. Why would they present a different text value than the encoded value itself?

Comment: Quick suggestion although it doesn't solve the issue and is a UX nightmare: Have your users click on something if they want to type in the value manually

Comment: This isn't a technical problem to solve - it's a business one. You've asked for "the actual result" - but there is **no** way for us (or SQL Server) to work out which row would be the correct answer. If the Excel file can't be changed then you *need* to be able to inform the operator that somethings gone wrong.

Comment: Or, to put it another way; Just given your example - tell us which row should be returned for `C000001`.

Comment: @Meherzad - and then it'll charge the customer the wrong price, mess up inventory, etc, because you picked the wrong one.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Tks for correcting

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever In the actual, the operator can scan the Barcode or key-in the visible id (if scanner not present or doesnt recognize) the query should always return Barcode # as of now. Any suggestion or any miracle help is most welcome.

Comment: Thank you all. Managed to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without stating where the input comes from (barcode / manual input) there is no way detecting this.

Also: The number below a barcode is usually the barcode number itself, which is also part of the barcode specification (afaik).

But, this is not always possible. I have a customer who uses a human readable ID as well as an RFID-tag. The RFID-ID is a 36 hex digit code which is not suitable for human input. The solution to distuingish between the two is the length of the key (as well as the input source). The human readable ID is always 4 digits.

So I can offer 3 solutions:

1. Take the input source into account when querying the database.
2. Print the barcode # below the barcode
3. Change the code length of either code.

Comment: Thank you. Managed to work with the BarCode manufacturer to fix the VisibleCode just by increasing the length by another single charater. Thanks for the suggestion provided.